# MySQL query feature item load first

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a php MySQL database table called job_lists. The sample table is:

```
ID | subject | description | featured | time
1 | any | any | 1 | any
2 | any | any | 0 | any
3 | any | any | 0 | any 
4 | any | any | 1 | any 
5 | any | any | 0 | any
6 | any | any | 1 | any
.. | ... | ... | ... | ...
```

I want to load featured = 1 first then featured = 0 in a paginated way if I have thousand data how can I do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily accomplish a custom order in `ORDER BY`

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN featured = 1 THEN '1'
              ELSE featured = '2' END ASC
```

Although in your case you just need a descendant order

```
ORDER BY featured DESC
```